# Why chmod command is not going to work here?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chmod

i am accessing another ununtu linux system by `ssh`

now when i am going to change the permission of any file in that system then it shows

```
chmod: changing permissions of `Android.mk': Read-only file system
chmod: changing permissions of `system_init.cpp': Read-only file system
```

i have tried with `sudo`  and login as `root`  but still not getting why i am not able to change the permission of that files.?

Comment: That's what "read-only" mounted means. You can only **read**. Chmod can't change anything since it tries to **write**.

Comment: Don't know much about android but you could try mounting that `fs` read-write. Not sure if android has a `fstab` ?

Comment: oh that is just android file system source code in one linux pc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the error message states the reason pretty clearly. Have you checked how the filesystem in question is mounted? Is the `ro` mount option set by any chance? If you have root access you can remount the filesystem without the read-only option, if that is a sensible thing to do in this case. It must have a reason why the fileystem was mounted read-only in the first place.

Comment: this is my ubyntu 11.4 system. Now how filesystem becomes read only? how can i change that permission?

Comment: Find out on which filesystem your files are located, try df . in the directory where your files are located. Look up the entry in your systems /etc/fstab, the mount options are located in the fourth column. Seen man mount on how to use the mount command and remount the fs in question without the ro-option.